# Telescopic Product involving Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, telescopic-series

> If
>   $$
> \left(1 + \frac{1}{1^2}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{(1 + i)^2}\right)
> \left(1 + \frac{1}{(1 + 2i)^2}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{(1 + (n-1)i)^2}\right) = \frac{10 +  8i}{1 + 8i}
> $$
>   find $n$

I came across the above problem a while ago, and the look and feel of it hints at a possible *telescopic sum*.

I tried to write the term inside the nth bracket in terms of the $(n-1)$-th bracket, but it didn't really help.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction, and tell me how to approach or solve the question?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1+\frac1{(1+ki)^2}=\frac{(1+ki)^2-i^2}{(1+ki)^2}
=\frac{(1+(k-1)i)(1+(k+1)i)}{(1+ki)^2}$$
etc.